# How can i get the function name from a .php file ? Need a php script

Tags: php

Suppose there is a input file. The file contains php class with many functions and public variable.

I need a php script that would take that input file and count how many php function are there.
This script will also print the function name like ..

```
public function hasMethod($method)
public function isVirtualField($field)
```

Can anyone post such php script to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get_class_methods()` will give you all methods in a given object or class name, see [PHP func ref](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php)

```
require_once('Model.php');
$methods = get_class_methods('Model');
print_r($methods);
```

Will show you all methods of the class `Model` in file `Model.php`

Comment: +1 but you don't even need to create an instance of this class, `get_class_methods()` accepts a string (the class name), too.

Comment: The class is defined inside a file named, Model.php. I need to read from that file.

Comment: @soulmerge: Brilliant, didn't know that (although it's clear in the linked ref ;-)

Comment: @guru: see the updated answer, you just require() the file and run the function

Answer (score 1):

```
class theclass {
    // constructor
    function theclass() {
        return;
    }

    function func1() {
        return;
    }

    // method 2
    function func2() {
        return;
    }
}

    $class_methods = get_class_methods('theclass');

foreach ($classFunctions as $functionName) {
    echo "$functionName\n";
}
```

Comment: I need to read from .php file. The Model class is defined in that Model.php file.